# Particle emitter / initial velocity of emitted particles

Tags: particles

I've created a pendulum that emits particles, which fall on a moving board.
The problem is that the particles inherit the speed of the pendulum, which is physically correct.

But I would prefer the particles to have no initial velocity or only z-initial velocity to get a more sine wave like pattern on the ground. Is this possible?

Here is a link to the original .blend: [Blender File](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/04OcsRW6Y_LizCFo7Ef8JXYJw#Pendel)

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: @Chris edited to provide the .blend file

Comment: Writing this as a comment since you specifically asked for only z initial velocity. Anywho, setting the initial velocity to match the velocity of the plane (roughly -20 y) eliminates the distortion.

Answer (score 0):

one way to solve this you could increase your z - speed to -50 m/s.

and change damping and friction of your plane to 1.

then you get this:

[image]